# Not able to add external user to VSTS/Azure DevOps

Tags: active-directory, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Today I was trying to add an external user to VSTS and got below error message.

> You are trying to invite a user from outside your directory, but
>   something went wrong. Please try again later. If the issue persists,
>   please contact support.

[image]

I have followed the step mentioned in below link and "External guest access" is enabled.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/add-external-user?view=azure-devops&viewFallbackFrom=vsts&tabs=new-nav

Not sure where I am going wrong with this and looking for a solution.

Comment: Maybe your admin has disabled invites?

Comment: You are spot on @juunas

Answer (score 2):

After signing-out and sign-in again it works.
It seems this happened after password reset for my AAD account.

> The reason was a missing refresh of the user AAD token. After
> completely signing out from Azue DevOps (deleting all browser caches)
> it was working.

Source: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/you-are-trying-to-invite-a-user-from-outside-your/395999

Comment: It happened same in my case. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Before this will work, you need to have the external domain added as an approved domain for collaboration. Then you will be able to invite them to your Office 365/Azure tenant. I had to have this approved through Global Security and then the work was done for our organization.

Comment: This isn't always required. By default in a new AAD tenant you can invite users from any domain.

Comment: Thanks @juunas. Good to know.

Comment: Ran into this issue, we have always been able to do invite users from any domain to view an approved project on devops.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I had a similar issue and discover that Project Collection Administrators/Owners manage the policy: Allow team and project administrators to invite new users.

Source [Azure DevOps Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/restrict-invitations?view=azure-devops)